# Changing .BuildConfig package

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-build

Is there a way to dynamically change the package of the generated file .BuildConfig?

I want to use `build.gradle` file to use the `applicationId` and change the package name between different builds.

Thanks

Comment: Btw what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am building an app with dynamic package name and need programatically to find the BuildConfiguration file. I don't want to use flavours with different package names, only the package of the generated file to be under the dynamic applicationId (or any other flags needed)

Answer (score 6):

I had also ApplicationId or Package declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`

> `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="xxx">`

Replacing `xxx` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The applicationId field just changes the packagename in the manifest. All classes will be still in the original package.

Comment: I know. I want to change the package of the generated file. Any Idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Change code in: Build.gradle (module):

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxx.yyyy" <-----!!!
    minSdkVersion ?
    targetSdkVersion ?
    versionCode ?
    versionName ?
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

After sync, APPLICATION_ID from BuildConfig has updated.

If you have problems with installation in emulator. Go to AVD Manager, and make STOP and Cold Boot Now.